# Scaling bitmap to notification size before API level 11

Tags: android, api, bitmap, notifications, scaling

For an App I am working on, I make use of notifications. I need to scale a Bitmap before I can use it as large icon for the notifications so I have the following code:

```
int width = (int) Constants.resources.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width);
int height = (int) Constants.resources.getDimension(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height);
```

This works from API level 11 onwards, but how would I do this on lower API levels?

Comment: Did you solve this at the end? I'm interested.